# Selecting specific columns in Table form hockey-reference.com

Tags: python, pandas

Beginner here. I was able to extract this Table from hockey-reference.com

It's regarding Goalies Statistics. I used this code to do so:

```
import requests
import pandas as pd

url = 'https://www.hockey-reference.com/leagues/NHL_2020_goalies.html'
html = requests.get(url).content
df_list = pd.read_html(html)
df = df_list[0]
print(df)
```

From that Table, I just need four columns, which are:

1. Rk
2. Player
3. SV%
4. QS%

So I guess what I wanna be able to do is to basically "identify" the 4 columns that I need but everything I tried failed.

I'm convinced this isn't really complicated, but I just can't figure it out.

Comment: your dataframe is a multi index column, so you could just drop the top level columns since they are not relevant, with `droplevel`, and then access your required columns: ``df.droplevel(level = 0, axis = 'columns').filter(['Rk', 'Player', 'SV%', 'QS%'])``. Also, you do not need `requests` module for this; you can pass url to pandas directly and it should work fine.

Comment: Nice!! Works perfectly! droplevel was new to me and I think it will be really useful in the future. Thanx a lot!!